# change a list of dictionaries to feature vector and target in scikit

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a list of dictionaries that contains features and the classification label.  I read from a CSV. How can I split it into a numpy array as required by the scikit for a classification task.
Code so far

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
          rowdicts =[{'feature1': 4, 'feature2':2,'target':"yes","feature3":0},{'feature1': 3, 'feature2': 2,'target':"no","feature3":1}]


    vec1 = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
    X = vec1.fit_transform(rowdicts)
```

What could be a good way to remove the target labels from the above vectorizer for a classification task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure out which columns mean what using `get_feature_names`:

```
print(vec1.get_feature_names())
```

output:

```
['feature1', 'feature2', 'feature3', 'target=no', 'target=yes']
```

Now that we know that we can just drop the `target=no` column:

```
X = numpy.delete(X, 3, axis=1)
```

Comment: here my target is the classification label that takes values as yes or no, but here it is shown as two different features.

Comment: Changed my answer to preserve the column with `yes` labels

Comment: I'm still confused as to why it shows target  as two different features with different values. Why is target not shown as one individual feature like feature1, feature2, feature3.

Comment: Ah, it's because your labels are strings. DictVectorizer doesn't know what 'yes' and 'no' mean so it just encodes them as features. As part of you CSV readin process you could replace 'yes' and 'no' with 1 and 0 or use my method, both will produce the same results.